# Change file contents with c++

Tags: c++

Consider the following file contents

```
[channels]
usecallerid=yes
cidsignalling=dtmf 
cidstart=dtmf


;group=0
usecallerid=yes
context=pstn-channels
channel=>5

;group=0
usecallerid=yes
context=pstn-channels
channel=>6

;group=0
usecallerid=yes
context=pstn-channels
channel=>7

;group=1
context=phone-channels
channel=>1-4
```

I just want to search for a channel an change some properties of that channel with c++. The point is that each channels' properties is written above the "channel" keyword.
For example, I need to change channel 5's context property to phone. 
How can I do so?

EDIT:

So I have finally found a way. I read the file line by line, looking for "group" keyword, after reaching this keyword, I start to push back each line to a string vector till I reach a line which contains "channel" keyword. Then I split the last line with "=" delimiter and compare the cell number 1 with "portNumber", then if they match, I search the string vector (the data block which begins with "group" and ends with "channel" keywords) for the property which user wants to change it, after finding this property I calculate the proper amount of offset to change the file's pointer position with seekg function, then I write data.
But the thing is each line has a limited amount of characters, that is when in case of inserting a longer line, other lines miss up. Consider the third line of block below

```
;group=0
usecallerid=yes
context=pstn-channels
channel=>131
```

if I want to change this line to something like "context=phone-channels", the result will be

```
;group=0
usecallerid=n
context=phone-channels
channel=>130
```

as you can see the second line gets the wrong value. I thought it would be useful to add some spaces at the end of each line before editing and it works but I suppose that this is not an efficient solution. So what do you think? I Hope that the question and the problem will be clear to you... .

And here's the code

```
bool changeConfigFiles(string addr, int portNumber, string key, string value)
{
    //
    char cmd[200];
    fstream targetFile(addr.c_str());
    string lines;
    int offset=0,pPosition;
    vector<string> helper,anotherHelper;
    vector<string> contentsBlock;
    //
    if (!targetFile.is_open())
    {
        return false;
    }
    //
    while(getline(targetFile, lines))
    {
        if(lines.find("group") != string::npos)
        {
            pPosition = targetFile.tellg();
            pPosition -= lines.length();
            contentsBlock.push_back(lines);
            while(getline(targetFile, lines))
            {
                if(lines.find("=>") != string::npos)
                {
                    helper = explode("=>",lines);
                    contentsBlock.push_back(lines);
                    break;
                }
                contentsBlock.push_back(lines);
            }
        }
        //
        if(helper.size() !=0 && strToInt(helper[1]) == portNumber)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<contentsBlock.size();i++)
            {
                if(contentsBlock[i].find(key) != string::npos)
                {
                    anotherHelper = explode("=",contentsBlock[i]);
                    targetFile.seekg(pPosition+offset-1);
                    targetFile << endl << anotherHelper[0] << "=" << value << endl;
                }
                offset += contentsBlock[i].length();
            }
            //
            helper.clear();
            targetFile.seekg(pPosition+offset);
        }
    contentsBlock.clear();
    }
    targetFile.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I fixed your tags. Since you are coding in C++, don't tag the question C.

Comment: This looks like an INI file. So, get an INI file parser. Boost has one.

Comment: You'll have much better luck getting an answer if you show what you have tried so far, as SO is not a code-writing service ...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No it's not. It's just a simple file which I added tags like "[]".

Comment: Not really an INI file because it has multiple identical keys in the same section.

Comment: OK, it's not a real ini file. Instead of inventing your own file format, that requires you to write a parser, why don't you use an existing file format that already has a good parser?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually it's one of asterisk's configuration files. So I have to use this file format.

Comment: That information should be in the question. It could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a known data layout for this file, I'm going to answer this as if it were a "how do I parse this file" question. In C++, [fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) is a simple way to natively parse files. Consider the following (which assumes you have a string split and a string IndexOf method, both of which are fairly trivial to write):

```
char** SplitString( _In_ char* string, _In_ char token, _Out_ int* tokenCount );
int IndexOf( _In_ char* string, _In_ char* search, _Out_ int* count, _Out_ int length );

CustomFileType* ParseFile( char* filename )
{
    int bufferSize = 10000;
    auto buffer = new char[ bufferSize];
    memset( buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    ifstream file( filename );

    file.read( buffer, bufferSize );

    file.close( );

    int blockCount = 0;
    auto blocks = SplitString( buffer, ';', &blockCount );

    CustomFileType* file = new CustomFileType( );

    for( int blockIndex = 0; blockIndex < blockCount; blockIndex++ )
    {
        Block* b = new Block( );
        b.PropertyX = GetValueOf( buffer, "PropertyX=" );
        b.PropertyY = GetValueOf( buffer, "PropertyY=" );   
        file.Blocks.Add( b );                     
    }
}

char* GetValueOf( char* buffer, char* key )
{
    int count = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int index = IndexOf( buffer, key, &count, &length );

    if( length == 0 || count == 0 ) return nullptr;

    auto output = new char[ length ];
    memcpy( output, &buffer[ index ], length );
    return output;
}
```

That roughly covers the idea of parsing. Break the file into blocks, read each element of each block, retrieve each value related to each key, convert to data type (which is not shown above) and assign to related property.

To change the values of the files, you can simply (what I call) un-parse it where you turn the data structure back into it's format. So read the object with the parser, change the value, and then un-parse it (or encode it, whichever term you prefer).

To changes values and write them back to the file, consider the actual problem at hand. You have already parsed the text into an object and you know the file format. So now it is a matter of replacing values on objects and writing them back to the file. Your file structure looks like it observes the following format:

[Header Info]

[Groups]

Where groups are seperated by a semicolon, and both header info and groups are defined by a collection of key-value pairs (x=y). So that being said, you need one method that knows how to write key value pairs (which should be trivial) and then another method that understands the header/group layout and can take in an object (probably of CustomFileType, as used in previous examples) and can read through that object and convert its values into your file format. Without actually writing the parser and writer for you, that's probably the best way I can explain it.